# How to split a dataframe randomly into rows but each cluster with exact same cumsum of a value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this in R:

```
      id             cost   conversion
1     11427661523     3.72       4
2      5422676555     0.16       0
3     11428224852    25.27      33
```

In total I have 99999 rows in this dataframe.
I will need to split this dataframe into n random groups. The number of the groups does't matter, but each group needs to have exact 5000 total conversions (sum). Each group doesn't need to have exact same number of rows.
And also, it will be good if the total (accumulated cost) of each group is similar.
I'm not sure how to approach this.

Thank you!

Comment: This could be more of an statistical question rather than a programming question

Comment: This is [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is NP-complete i.e. very hard to solve for large sizes. Check out the link for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building a cumulative sum field and then 5,000 multiplier group field for splitting into a list of data frames.

```
df <- within(df, {
  raw_cum_sum <- cumsum(conversion)
  grp_5000 <- as.integer(raw_cum_sum / 5000)

  cum_sum_conv <- raw_cum_sum - (5000 * grp_5000)
})

df_list <- split(random_df, random_df$grp_5000)
```

Please note:

- Not all data frames will `cumsum`  to exactly 5,000 only up to last *conversion* value nearest to 5,000 multiplier.
- Only the very last data frame would not accumulate to ~5,000 being the remainder after last 5,000 multiplier.

---

To demonstrate with random data of N=99,999 observations:

```
set.seed(7162019)

### BUILD DATA
random_df <- data.frame(
  id = sample(c("sas", "stata", "spss", "python", "r", "julia"), 99999, replace=TRUE),
  conversion = sample(1:50, 99999, replace=TRUE),
  cost = round(runif(99999, 1, 50), 2)
)

### RANDOMIZE ORDER
random_df <- random_df[sample(1:nrow(random_df)),]

### CREATE GROUPINGS 
random_df <- within(random_df, {
  raw_cum_sum <- cumsum(conversion)
  grp_5000 <- as.integer(raw_cum_sum / 5000)

  cum_sum_conv <- raw_cum_sum - (5000 * grp_5000)
})

# LIST OF 511 DATA FRAMES
df_list <- split(random_df, random_df$grp_5000)
```

**Head Output**

```
lapply(df_list[1:5], head)

# $`0`
#          id conversion  cost raw_cum_sum grp_5000 cum_sum_conv
# 15077 julia         34  3.26          34        0           34
# 65370   sas         29 30.32          63        0           63
# 64979   sas         13 35.27          76        0           76
# 50733  spss         15  6.59          91        0           91
# 19582     r         14 28.48         105        0          105
# 488   julia         41 37.81         146        0          146
# 
# $`1`
#          id conversion  cost raw_cum_sum grp_5000 cum_sum_conv
# 25457 python         44 39.02        5025        1           25
# 60543  stata         38 25.52        5063        1           63
# 94722   spss         28 45.36        5091        1           91
# 10915   spss         34 22.32        5125        1          125
# 27112 python         10 44.70        5135        1          135
# 93532   spss         47 47.29        5182        1          182
# 
# $`2`
#          id conversion  cost raw_cum_sum grp_5000 cum_sum_conv
# 41431   sas         28  8.22       10004        2            4
# 36085     r         40 16.85       10044        2           44
# 25825 stata         11  8.24       10055        2           55
# 4991  stata         41 16.05       10096        2           96
# 13679 stata         14  4.21       10110        2          110
# 96374   sas         48  7.45       10158        2          158
# 
# $`3`
#           id conversion  cost raw_cum_sum grp_5000 cum_sum_conv
# 50597 python         37 44.60       15026        3           26
# 95745   spss         25 14.54       15051        3           51
# 25249 python         25 36.44       15076        3           76
# 50466      r         19 45.58       15095        3           95
# 11483  stata         10 11.77       15105        3          105
# 79463  stata          3  6.28       15108        3          108
# 
# $`4`
#          id conversion  cost raw_cum_sum grp_5000 cum_sum_conv
# 78364      r         34 49.14       20013        4           13
# 98409 python         32  6.29       20045        4           45
# 44207      r          9 23.27       20054        4           54
# 87802    sas         18 14.37       20072        4           72
# 61991  stata         45 12.79       20117        4          117
# 56245  stata         25 17.33       20142        4          142
```

**Tail output** *(notice the 511th item, named `$510` does not accumulate ~5,000)*

```
lapply(df_list[507:511], tail)

# $`506`
#           id conversion  cost cum_sum_conv grp_5000 raw_cum_sum
# 34219  julia         27 37.57         4851      506     2534851
# 89070   spss         17 28.64         4868      506     2534868
# 99942 python         37 12.60         4905      506     2534905
# 64474 python         14  3.98         4919      506     2534919
# 33832   spss         42  6.73         4961      506     2534961
# 59165  julia          1 37.78         4962      506     2534962
# 
# $`507`
#          id conversion  cost cum_sum_conv grp_5000 raw_cum_sum
# 93594 stata         35 44.97         4816      507     2539816
# 10559     r         28 18.81         4844      507     2539844
# 85380 stata         37  3.76         4881      507     2539881
# 14015   sas         40  1.32         4921      507     2539921
# 96312   sas         22 15.49         4943      507     2539943
# 2891  julia         23 28.76         4966      507     2539966
# 
# $`508`
#           id conversion  cost cum_sum_conv grp_5000 raw_cum_sum
# 46716  julia          5 12.48         4813      508     2544813
# 63548   spss          8  2.00         4821      508     2544821
# 20121 python         23 44.53         4844      508     2544844
# 24958   spss         40 21.99         4884      508     2544884
# 8699   stata         39  1.55         4923      508     2544923
# 49847    sas         46 18.25         4969      508     2544969
# 
# $`509`
#           id conversion  cost cum_sum_conv grp_5000 raw_cum_sum
# 89785  julia         15 24.50         4860      509     2549860
# 53959 python         50 22.43         4910      509     2549910
# 17296      r         10  7.47         4920      509     2549920
# 82101   spss         34 16.78         4954      509     2549954
# 52995  stata          2 10.26         4956      509     2549956
# 98874    sas         33 40.04         4989      509     2549989
# 
# $`510`
#          id conversion  cost cum_sum_conv grp_5000 raw_cum_sum
# 95473 stata         28 22.36         3416      510     2553416
# 83271   sas         33 35.30         3449      510     2553449
# 88128 julia         43  6.55         3492      510     2553492
# 84310     r         35 47.57         3527      510     2553527
# 26173 stata         13 35.86         3540      510     2553540
# 26624 stata         28  3.57         3568      510     2553568
```